# Solr: MLT filter by a field in matched doc

Tags: solr

MoreLikeThis can return the matched doc. My question is that can i somehow pass in a query param to indicate that i would like to filter on a field value of the matched doc? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Please include some context too.

Comment: @aichnyu, Suppose there is a field called PriceRating (value ranges from 0 to 5). We know that the first block of the MoreLikeThis result is the matched doc, then it follows a block of MoreLikeThis results. These results needs to have similar PriceRating as that of the matched doc. Say, the matched doc has PriceRating as 1, then i expect the MoreLikeThis results has PriceRating as 0, 1, 2, but not 3, 4, 5. Thanks a lot for offering help!